# Obtaining a past-the-end pointer using the address of an array

Tags: c++, c, c++11, undefined-behavior, c11

In C and C++, it is often useful to use a past-the-end pointer to write functions that can operate on arbitrarily large arrays. C++ gives a `std::end` overload to make this easier. In C, on the other hand, I've found it's not uncommon to see a macro defined and used like this:

```
#define ARRAYLEN(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

// ...

int a [42];
do_something (a, a + ARRAYLEN (a));
```

I've also seen a pointer arithmetic trick used to let such functions operate on single objects:

```
int b;
do_something (&b, &b + 1);
```

It occured to me that something similar could be done with arrays, since they are considered by C (and, I believe, C++) to be "complete objects." Given an array, we can derive a pointer to an array immediately after it, dereference that pointer, and use array-to-pointer conversion on the resulting reference to an array to get a past-the-end pointer for the original array:

```
#define END(array) (*(&array + 1))

// ...

int a [42];
do_something (a, END (a));
```

My question is this: **In dereferencing a pointer to a non-existent array object, does this code exhibit undefined behaviour?** I'm interested in what the most recent revisions of both C and C++ have to say about this code (not because I intend to use it, as there are better ways of achieving the same result, but because it's an interesting question).

Comment: I'm suprised this doesn't have an answer yet, but after doing a bunch of reading I think the consensus is that pointing one past the end of an array is a valid pointer that cannot be dereferenced. A common passage from the C standard that is quoted is `6.5.6/8`.  In C++ it is `5.7/5`. If you're interested, here's a [diff checker link](http://www.diffchecker.com/6s57ow8f).

Comment: @remyabel This seems to indicate that the code is not legal. For the purpose of pointer arithmetic, C (not sure about C++) considers a complete object to be equivalent to the sole element of an array of extent 1 (in this case, the array of type `int[42]` is the sole element of an array of type `int[1][42]`). `6.5.8` explicitly forbids dereferencing a past-the-end pointer (in an evaluated context), such as the pointer formed by `&array + 1`, which is being dereferenced.

Comment: @StuartOlsen: But is array-to-pointer conversion (commonly called decay) an evaluated context?  It doesn't use the value of the object, only its address.

Comment: @BenVoigt I believe the evaluated context rule is referring to the indirection being evaluated (i.e., `*ptr` appears outside of a `sizeof`/`alignof`/`_Alignof` expression). "If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated" - `6.5.6.8`, N1570

Comment: @StuartOlsen: Those undoubtedly are unevaluated contexts.  But others might be.  In C++, for example, binding a reference doesn't evaluate the object it is binding to.  (Note at section 5.3.1 paragraph 1)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, but I think the rule is talking about the indirection operator being evaluated, not the resulting lvalue's value being evaluated. In other words, if I understand the text correctly, even `int* p = NULL; *p;` is not valid, at least in C.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, bad example. Better would have been `int a [1]; a [1];` 6.5.6.8 in C definitely makes this illegal, irrespective of the lack of lvalue-rvalue conversion. For consistency's sake, that should make `*NULL` illegal, but if UB for unary `*` is determined in general by lvalue-rvalue conversion, I'm not so sure it is, because there is no such conversion in that expression. That's straying out of the scope of the question, though.

Comment: @Stuart: Jerry Coffin found [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232) that explicitly mentions the `*p;` case and says it doesn't trigger conversion to rvalue, therefore no undefined behavior.  So my earlier comment was mistaken.  (Not sure how it works to force a read via a volatile pointer, then.)

Comment: @BenVoigt As I read it, the proposed resolution would definitely make the code legal in C++, since `(&array[1])` would produce a so-called "empty lvalue", and the array-to-pointer conversion would not invoke the UB clause. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's made it out of drafting status yet; N3797 does not include the proposed wording.

Comment: @Stuart: No, but the comments concerning pulling in the language from C (`&*p` is a no-op) declare that C++ already handles that, because creating an lvalue by dereferencing an invalid pointer is not UB, only lvalue-rvalue conversion on such an lvalue is.

Answer (score 1):

I've used that in my own code, as `(&arr)[1]`.

I'm quite sure it is safe.  Array to pointer decay is not "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion", although it starts with an lvalue and ends with an rvalue.

Comment: Does either standard allow you to indirect through a pointer which does not point to an object (e.g., the pointer `&arr + 1`) if the resulting lvalue (reference) does not undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Both languages make reference to the "object" referred to by the pointer, which seems to imply that there must be an object of appropriate type at the location described by the pointer to dereference it. The best I can find is that C allows such an indirection to occur when immediately canceled by the address-of operator (e.g., `&*NULL`), which isn't quite what's happening here.

Comment: @Stuart: The C++ Standard contains (4p8) a note to that effect, and makes the operand of the `&` address-of operator an example... but it's not limited to the `&` operator, it applies anywhere that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not appear.  Also, the rule which makes access through an invalid pointer value undefined behavior is 4.1p2, and applies only to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour.

`a` is of type `array of 42 int`.

`&a` is of type `pointer to array of 42 int`. (Note this is not an array-to-pointer conversion)

`&a + 1` is also of type `pointer to array of 42 int`

5.7p5 states:

> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and [...] otherwise, the behavior is undefined

The pointer does not point to an element of an array object.  It points to an array object.  So the "otherwise, the behaviour is undefined" is true.  Behaviour is undefined.

Comment: At least in C++, this is incorrect.  There's a rule that allows every object to be treated as an array of size 1.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Standard reference?

Comment: 5.7p4 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Comment: @BenVoigt: It is a pointer to an array object, so 5.7p4 doesn't apply.  Although, I would tend to think this is a defect.  I think 5.7p4 should read "..., a pointer that isn't a pointer to an element of an array..." instead of "..., a pointer to a nonarray object..."

Comment: Yes, clearly the intent is the behavior I gave in my comment when paraphrasing.  Or perhaps a pointer to an array object is considered also a pointer to its first element, which makes the pointer arithmetic valid.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos The N1570 draft for C says, "a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." Odd that C++ uses a different rule.

Comment: Defect reported to ISO here: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/4XwebGSKsaA

Comment: @AndrewTomazos That forum isn't an official channel; a defect report isn't submitted until emailed to the maintainer mentioned on the latest DR list, currently wmm@edg.com .

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Are there instructions somewhere how to format the email?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The instructions here http://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-library-issue say post to std-discussion first.  Shrug.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Annoyingly, the process is at the discretion of the maintainer. In my experience it is better to keep CWG reports relatively brief lest they be cut to size.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Those instructions are mainly to weed out the non language lawyers. Given that this was already recognized and fixed in C, this should be uncontroversial enough to go right to committee.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior in C, dereferencing a pointer that points beyond an existing object always is unless it is itself part of a bigger object that contains more elements.

But the basic idea of using `&array + 1` is correct, whenever `array` is an lvalue. (There are cases where arrays aren't lvalues.) In that case that is a valid pointer operation. Now to obtain a pointer to the first element you just have to cast that back to the base type. In your case that would be

```
(int*)(&array + 1)
```

The value of a pointer to array is guaranteed to be the same value as a pointer to its first element, only the types differ.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to make such an expression type agnostic such that you could put this in a generic macro, unless you cast to `void*`. (With the gcc `typeof` extension you could do, e.g)
So you'd better stick to the portable `(array)+ARRAYLEN(array)`, that one should work in all cases.

In a weird corner case an array that is part of a `struct` and is returned as rvalue from a function is not an lvalue. I think that the standard allows pointer arithmetic here, too, bu t I never understood that construction completely, so I am not sure that it will work in that case.